# Spark timeseries Changepoint detection

Tags: apache-spark, time-series

Is there a Changepoint Algorithm implemention for Apache spark? Forinstance such as Functional Pruning Optimal Partitioning ([FPOP](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-016-9636-3))

Comment: I could not find any such implementation, you can also search for here https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=(text~%22Pruning%22%20AND%20text~%22Functional%22%20or%20text~%22fpop%22)%20and%20project%3DSpark

Comment: No. There is not. That's too specific and I don't think there is something planned